# Multipart httpresponse with django

Tags: django, python-3.x, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I would like some help about my code. My goal is to send at the same time string variables as a ini plain text and a bmp file in an httpResponse.

For the moment I insert the decoded bytes of the bmp file in an ini parameter, take into account that I communicate with an interphone which is only client but not server so I can only make httpresponses but no requests.

If I base64 encode my image, I'll need to change the software of our interphone to decode it, for the moment I can't, can you tell me if base64 encode bytes is mandatory in my case ?

I made some researches on the web and I saw that people base64 encode their images or they make multipart response.

Could you help me to implement a multipart response please, even hand made, that would interest me ?

I show you how I do for the moment, I put the image in the "string" ini parameter:

```
    def send_bmp():
        outputConfig = io.StringIO()

        outputConfig.write('[RETURN_INFO]\r\n')
        outputConfig.write('config_id=255\r\n')
        outputConfig.write('config_type=2\r\n')
        outputConfig.write('action=3\r\n')
        outputConfig.write('[DATABASE]\r\n')

        file = open(django_settings.TMP_DIR+'/qrcode.bmp', 'rb').read()

        outputConfig.write('size_all='+str(len(file))+'\r\n')
        outputConfig.write('string='+file.decode('iso-8859-1')+'\r\n')
        outputConfig.write('csum='+str(sum(file))+'\r\n')

        body = outputConfig.getvalue()

        httpR = HttpResponse(body, content_type='text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1')

        httpR['Content-Length'] = len(body)

        return httpR
```

Here is the response I get :

https://gist.github.com/Ezekiah/e6fd50f13c05f338f27a

Answer (score 0):

If you need to mix the image file content with the rest of the response I think you have to use Base64 encoding. If it is possible to return the ini parameters in one request and the file in another Django provides a [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) class(subclass of StreamingHttpResponse) that you can use to return the bmp file in chunks, like this:

```py
from django.http import FileResponse
def send_bmp(request):
    file = open(django_settings.TMP_DIR+'/qrcode.bmp', 'rb')
    return FileResponse(file)
```